# How to hide top bar (color one with SharePoint written in it)

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I manage to hide top ribbon as well as search bar with css:

```
#suiteBar, #s4-ribbonrow{display:none}
.ms-designer-ribbon{
    display:none !important;
}
#searchInputBox {
    display:none;
}
#suiteBarLeft{
    display: none;
}
#suiteBarRight{
    display: none;
}
.ms-belltown-anonShow{
    display: none!important;
}
 .ms-displayInlineBlock{
       display: none;
 }
#titleAreaBox #SearchBox{
    display: none !important;
}
#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea
{
display:none!important;
}
.ms-belltown-authenticated #suiteBar {
    display: none;
}
```

However when i enter the page or navigate to another page on site i can still see this top ribbon for a split second? I included this css in master page so i dont know why does it display this ribbon for a split second. Could some advise please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For anyone interested, i solved it by also making my master page  custom master page. Then the classes got applied also in this middle step.

Comment: I know you've solved your issue, but if you had the script loaded via a Code editor of some sort on the page itself, the page may have partially loaded by the time your CSS was ran. To prevent that you'd need to put the CSS early(ier?) in the Header, so no visibile objects were created before the CSS could take effect.